# React component won't take onChange event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, onchange, rating

Obligatory "new to react" paragraph here. I have this rating component I got from material-ui and i'm trying to send the value to a database.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

const labels = {
  0.5: 'Worst of the Worst',
  1: 'Bad',
  1.5: 'Poor',
  2: 'Passable',
  2.5: 'Ok',
  3: 'Good',
  3.5: 'Damn Good',
  4: 'Great',
  4.5: 'Love',
  5: 'Perfection',
};

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 200,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default function HoverRating(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);
  const [hover, setHover] = React.useState(-1);

  const classes = useStyles();

  const onRatingChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    props.reduxDispatch ({ type: "RATING_CHANGE", value: event.target.value 
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Rating
        name="hover-feedback"
        value={value}
        defaultValue={0}
        precision={0.5}
        size="large"
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
          console.log("your newValue is " +  newValue)
        }}
        onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
          setHover(newHover);
        }}
        { onRatingChange }
      />
      <br/>
      {value !== null && <Box ml={2}>{labels[hover !== -1 ? hover : value]}</Box>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It doesn't like something about my onRatingChange function. I've moved it all over the place and it's still throwing errors. I just really don't understand the issue. I'm mostly getting-

"./src/components/Rating.js
  Line 54:11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

I've been at this for hours and I salvation.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from:

```
{ onRatingChange }
```

to:

```
onRatingChange={onRatingChange}
```

and change your file extension from `.js` to `.jsx` because you are using the JSX syntax

Answer (score 0):

First, you appear the be storing the rating in two places: in your local state (with `React.useState`), and from the looks of your `onRatingChange` function, in a Redux store somewhere. It would be a good idea to pick one, and use that.

As for the direct answer to your question, your syntax is wrong. You're writing your `Rating` component in the following way:

```
<Rating
  // ...
  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    console.log("your newValue is " +  newValue)
  }}
  // ...
  { onRatingChange }
/>
```

The `Rating` component expects an `onChange` prop. I assume you want your `onRatingChange` function to be called when the rating changes. As such, you'd write:

```
<Rating
  // ...
  onChange={onRatingChange}
/>
```

The complication here though is that you're trying to register two different handlers for the rating change event. The bottom line is, decide on one, and then pass that as a callback function to the `onChange` prop.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for the explanation!